# What are Makefile.am and Makefile.in?

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

These two files are mostly seen in open source projects.

What are they for, and how do they work?

Comment: See Autotools Mythbuster ( https://autotools.info/ ).

Answer (score 478, accepted):

`Makefile.am` is a programmer-defined file and is used by `automake` to generate the `Makefile.in` file (the `.am` stands for **a**uto**m**ake).
The `configure` script typically seen in source tarballs will use the `Makefile.in` to generate a `Makefile`.

The [`configure` script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) itself is generated from a programmer-defined file named either `configure.ac` or `configure.in` (deprecated). I prefer `.ac` (for **a**uto**c**onf) since it differentiates it from the generated `Makefile.in` files and that way I can have rules such as `make dist-clean` which runs `rm -f *.in`. Since it is a generated file, it is not typically stored in a revision system such as Git, SVN, Mercurial or CVS, rather the `.ac` file would be.

Read more on [GNU Autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system).
Read about [`make`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) and [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) first, then learn about [`automake`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automake), [`autoconf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf), [`libtool`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Libtool), etc.

Comment: What does `.in` stand for?

Comment: The `.in` extension means that it's input for `configure` to massage, not a final file that should be used (e.g. with `make`).  If you're curious as to why this seems "ridiculously" complicated, try reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26832773/939557  These days with GitHub, etc. becoming a common distribution channel some of autoconf's assumptions are breaking down: people are obtaining the source directly from the source code control tool, rather than using a source distribution tarball created by maintainers.

Comment: This seems at odds with the emacs source; it has `Makefile.in` which generates `Makefile` using "configure".

Comment: @daraul I think `Makefile.am` is used to generate `Makefile.in`, which is used as input to generate `Makefile`.

Answer (score 81):

**Simple example**

Shamelessly adapted from: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Creating-amhello.html and tested on Ubuntu 14.04 Automake 1.14.1.

**Makefile.am**

```
SUBDIRS = src
dist_doc_DATA = README.md
```

**README.md**

```
Some doc.
```

**configure.ac**

```
AC_INIT([automake_hello_world], [1.0], [bug-automake@gnu.org])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([
 Makefile
 src/Makefile
])
AC_OUTPUT
```

**src/Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = autotools_hello_world
autotools_hello_world_SOURCES = main.c
```

**src/main.c**

```
#include <config.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  puts ("Hello world from " PACKAGE_STRING);
  return 0;
}
```

**Usage**

```
autoreconf --install
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make
sudo make install
autotools_hello_world
sudo make uninstall
```

This outputs:

```
Hello world from automake_hello_world 1.0
```

**Notes**

- `autoreconf --install` generates several template files which should be tracked by Git, including `Makefile.in`. It only needs to be run the first time.
- `make install` installs:

  - the binary to `/usr/local/bin`
  - `README.md` to `/usr/local/share/doc/automake_hello_world`

[On GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-cheat/tree/63278c7ac22721f7fa089cba32e93adf87724e3c/autotools/hello-world) for you to try it out.

Comment: Why should one keep generated files under VCS (this can be not only Git BTW)?

Comment: @VictorYarema I forgot why I reached that conclusion! Let me know if you find out.

Comment: Shouldn't `autotools_hello_world` instead of `autoconf_hello_world`? in your Usage section?

Answer (score 48):

### **DEVELOPER runs `autoconf` and `automake`:**

1. **autoconf**  -- creates shippable **configure** script
   (which the installer will later **run** to make the **Makefile**)

- [‘autoconf’ is a macro processor.](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/%7Eadl/dl/autotools.pdf)
- [It converts **configure.ac**, which is a shell script using macro instructions, into **configure**, a full-fledged shell script.](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/%7Eadl/dl/autotools.pdf)

2. **automake**  - creates shippable **Makefile.in** data file
   (which **configure** will later **read** to make the **Makefile**)

- [Automake helps with creating portable and GNU-standard compliant **Makefiles**.](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/%7Eadl/dl/autotools.pdf)
- [‘automake’ creates complex **Makefile.in**s from simple **Makefile.am**s](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/%7Eadl/dl/autotools.pdf)

---

### **INSTALLER runs `configure`, `make` and `sudo make install`:**

```
./configure       # Creates  Makefile        (from     Makefile.in).  
make              # Creates  the application (from the Makefile just created).  

sudo make install # Installs the application 
                  #   Often, by default its files are installed into /usr/local
```

---

---

### INPUT/OUTPUT MAP

***Notation below is roughly:** inputs --> programs --> outputs*

**DEVELOPER runs these:**

configure.ac -> **autoconf** -> **configure** (script) --- (*.**ac** = **a**uto**c**onf)
*configure.in --> **autoconf** -> **configure** (script)  --- (`configure.in` depreciated.  Use configure.ac)*

Makefile.am -> **automake** -> Makefile.in ----------- (*.**am** = **a**uto**m**ake)

**INSTALLER runs these:**

Makefile.in -> **configure** -> *Makefile* (*.**in** = **in**put file)

*Makefile* -> **make** ----------> (puts new software in your downloads or temporary directory)
*Makefile* -> **make install** -> (puts new software in system directories)

---

"**autoconf** is an extensible package of M4 macros that produce shell scripts to automatically configure software source code packages. These scripts can adapt the packages to many kinds of UNIX-like systems without manual user intervention. Autoconf creates a configuration script for a package from a template file that lists the operating system features that the package can use, in the form of M4 macro calls."

"**automake** is a tool for automatically generating Makefile.in files compliant with the GNU Coding Standards. Automake requires the use of Autoconf."

**Manuals:**

- **[GNU AutoTools](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/index.html#Top)** (The definitive manual on this stuff)
- **[m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html)** (used by autoconf)
- **[autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)**
- **[automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/)**

**Free online tutorials:**

- **[Using GNU Autotools](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/%7Eadl/dl/autotools.pdf)**

---

### ***Example:***

*The main **configure.ac** used to build LibreOffice is over 12k lines of code, (but there are also 57 other configure.ac files in subfolders.)*

*From this my generated **configure** is over 41k lines of code.*

*And while the **Makefile.in** and **Makefile** are both only 493 lines of code.  (But, there are also 768 more Makefile.in's in subfolders.)*

Answer (score 21):

[reference](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/what-is-the-meaning-of-makefile-makefile-am-makefile-in-390380/) :

Makefile.am -- a user input file to automake

configure.in -- a user input file to autoconf

---

autoconf generates configure from configure.in

automake gererates Makefile.in from Makefile.am

configure generates Makefile from Makefile.in

For ex:

```
$]
configure.in Makefile.in
$] sudo autoconf
configure configure.in Makefile.in ... 
$] sudo ./configure
Makefile Makefile.in
```

Comment: So Makefile.in should be in the tar.gz file when you make dist, right?

Comment: @KeminZhou Yes. Non-developers are not supposed to run `automake`. They should have `Makefile.in` in tarball.

Comment: Usually developers use autotools to generate configure to be used by regular users.