# Confused about configure script and Makefile.in

Tags: makefile, configure, autoconf

I'm currently learning how to use the `autoconf`/`automake` toolchain.  I seem to have a general understanding of the workflow here - basically you have a `configure.ac` script which generates an executable `configure` file.  The generated `configure` script is then executed by the end user to generate `Makefile`s, so the program can be built/installed.

So the installation for a typical end-user is basically:

```
./configure
make
make install
make clean
```

Okay, now here's where I'm confused:

As a developer, I've noticed that the auto-generated configure script sometimes won't run, and will error with:

```
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `somedir/Makefile.in'
```

This confuses me, because I thought the configure script is supposed to *generate* the `Makefile.in`.  So Googling around for some answers, I've discovered that this can be fixed with an `autogen.sh` script, which basically "resets" the state of the `autoconf` environment.  A typical `autogen.sh` script would be something like:

```
aclocal \
&& automake --add-missing \
&& autoconf
```

Okay fine.  But as an end-user who's downloaded countless tarballs throughout my life, I've *never* had to use an `autogen.sh` script.  All I did was uncompress the tarball, and do the usual configure/make/make install/make clean routine.

But as a developer who's now *using* `autoconf`, it seems that `configure` doesn't actually run unless you run `autogen.sh` first.  So I find this very confusing, because I thought the end-user shouldn't have to run `autogen.sh`.

So why do I have to run `autogen.sh` first - in order for the configure script to find `Makefile.in`?  Why doesn't the configure script simply generate it?

Comment: GNU Autoconf (or perhaps GNU Automake) comes with a convenient `autoreconf` script that does the same thing as `autogen.sh` and more. As for why you need to run it, do you have a `Makefile.am` in the `somedir` subdirectory for Automake to find `somedir/Makefile.am` and generate `somedir/Makefile.in` from it?

Comment: If there is an `autoreg.sh` script, then run it. If not, then run `autoupdate && autoreconf -f -i`. Both should produce a `configure` for you to run. It is sad it is not clearly stated in the Autotools manuals, but it is par for the course with Autotools. By the way, I believe `autogen.sh` is a wrapper script for `autoreconf -f -i` (maybe with a verbose option).

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In order to really understand the autotools utilities you have to remember where they come from: they come from an open source world where there are (a) developers who are working from a source code repository (CVS, Git, etc.) and creating a tar file or similar containing source code and putting that tar file up on a download site, and (b) end-users who are getting the source code tar file, compiling that source code on their system and using the resulting binary.  Obviously the folks in group (a) also compile the code and use the resulting binary, but the folks in group (b) don't have or need, often, all the tools for development that the folks in group (a) need.

So the use of the tools is geared towards this split, where the people in group (b) don't have access to autoconf, automake, etc.

When using autoconf, people generally check in the `configure.ac` file (input to autoconf) into source control but do not check in the output of autoconf, the `configure` script (some projects do check in the `configure` script of course: it's up to you).

When using automake, people generally check in the `Makefile.am` file (input to automake) but do not check in the output of automake: `Makefile.in`.

The `configure` script basically looks at your system for various optional elements that the package may or may not need, where they can be found, etc.  Once it finds this information, it can use it to convert various `XXX.in` files (typically, but not solely, `Makefile.in`) into `XXX` files (for example, `Makefile`).

So the steps generally go like this: write `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` and check them in.  To build the project from source code control checkout, run autoconf to generate `configure` from `configure.ac`.  Run automake to generate `Makefile.in` from `Makefile.am`.  Run configure to generate `Makefile` from `Makefile.in`.  Run make to build the product.

When you want to release the source code (if you're developing an open source product that makes source code releases) you run autoconf and automake, then bundle up the source code with the `configure` and `Makefile.in` files, so that people building your source code release just need make and a compiler and don't need any autotools.

Because the order of running autoconf and automake (and libtool if you use it) can be tricky there are scripts like autogen.sh and autoreconf, etc. which are checked into source control to be used by developers building from source control, but these are not needed/used by people building from the source code release tar file etc.

Autoconf and automake are often used together but you can use autoconf without automake, if you want to write your own `Makefile.in`.

Comment: From your description, a `Makefile.am` is not needed in the dist tarball. I just tried building a program from its dist , I `rm Makefile.am` and `make` exited with error `make: *** No rule to make target 'Makefile.am', needed by 'Makefile.in'.  Stop.`

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that it's not needed.  Autoconf was created for free software packages and a dist tarball for a free software package should contain all the files that are needed to modify it and rebuild it, and that includes Makefile.am.  If the user _wanted_ to modify the code they would install autotools, make the change, and rebuild, so they need all those extra files in the dist tarball.  The goal is to ensure they don't _have to_ install autotools, if they don't want to modify the software.

Answer (score 3):

For this error:

```
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `somedir/Makefile.in'
```

In the directory where the configure.ac is located in the Makefile.am  add a line with the subdirectory `somedir`

```
SUBDIRS = somedir
```

Inside `somedir` put a `Makefile.am` with all the description. then run `automaker --add-missing`

A better description can be found in 7.1 Recursing subdirectories automake manual.
https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html