# Rpmbuild copying folders specified by a mapping file

Tags: bash, cp

Currently, working with rhel. Need to create a script that can use a mapping file (source and target need to be dynamic). What file type should be used for the mapping file (.csv, .txt, .json)?

- End directory in a slash e.g. `src/`
- `-r` can be used against a file e.g. `cp -r src/file.fil tgt/`
- script will be kicked off by the spec file and files will be copied during build
- source and target need to be dynamic

Script example

`cp -r src/file.fil tgt/`

Mapping file

`<src>\t<tgt>\n` e.g. `src/file.fil \t tgt/ \n` OR `'src/file.fil'\t'tgt/'\n`

Comment: what is your shell? bash? from the man page -r is for recursive copying.

Comment: Bash. Yes, I know. I'm trying to figure out the file type for the mapping file that the bash script will read from.

Comment: What this has to do with the `rpmbuild` and `rhel` tag ?

Comment: Tags have been removed. @iamauser

Comment: Maybe you should generate a bunch of `install` commands and write them into your `.spec` file's `%files` section by way of a script? It's not too uncommon to have a skeleton  `.spec.in` template and then generate the final deliverable from that programmatically, perhaps by way of a simple `sed` script.

Comment: @tripleee this sounds really great! My problem is finding resources to uncover this approach. This is the first time I'm hearing about the `.spec.in` template. No search results populate in the Fedora docs for `.spec.in`. Where can I read up on this?

Comment: @phil-o-o Here's an starting point https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531827/what-are-makefile-am-and-makefile-in

Answer (score 0):

xargs can be used for that

```
xargs --arg-file your-file.txt cp
```

file should contain lines like

```
file1 tgt/
file2 tgt/
```

or a for loop reading from a file with just source file names provided that your target is constant

```
for f in $(cat yourfile.txt); do
    cp "$f" tgt/
done
```

or even

```
while read src tgt; do
    cp "$src" "$tgt"
done < yourfile.txt
```

Comment: this does not work as the `tgt` directory needs to be dynamic. `file2` may need to go to a different file path.

Comment: so your file should contain that mapping, file1 tgt1/
file2 tgt2/ and so on. Correct?

Comment: Downvote; still broken, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308990/xargs-is-incorrectly-copying-my-src-dir-to-one-tgt-directory

Comment: The loops are basically the way to go but both attempts suffer from newbie problems; run them through http://shellcheck.net/ for details.

Comment: newbie?! @tripleee

Comment: Quoting errors are indicative of limited experience with shell programming. Many developers never get past the copy/paste stage with the shell, even if they manage to write serious applications in other languages. I encourage you to try the site I linked, and maybe review https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls which has many forward links to a FAQ etc.

Comment: The Unix shell features many arcane idiosyncrasies which are based in the long, organic development of the Bourne family of shells; learning to recognize at least the most common ones will help you realize just how many poorly-written shell scripts there are even in critical production systems.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, mostly because they move apart from the 'newbie' approach. I've been writing bash scripts like 15 years and read ABS guide completely. Next time if someone misses a couple of quotes don't rush to call him newbie, it's not enough evidence.