# Cannot install gccgo on windows 10

Tags: windows, go, gcc, gccgo

I want to install gccgo, but I am on windows. I read the [Setting up and using gccgo](https://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo) page on the golang page. The page said

> The simplest way to install gccgo is to install a GCC binary release built to include Go support. GCC binary releases are available from [various websites](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html) and are typically included as part of GNU/Linux distributions. We expect that most people who build these binaries will include Go support.

When i went to that page, I saw that windows had two methods of installing. I has used mingw before so I tried `gcc testfile.go` in my powershell terminal, but it said:

```
gcc.exe: error: testfile.go.go: Go compiler not installed on this system
```

I then tried to install the other compiler: [Cygwin](https://sourceware.org/cygwin/). I followed [this](https://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/) tutorial, but it also yielded the exact same result.

Does anyone know how to install gccgo on windows (10)?

I also tried [Installing from source](https://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo#Source_code), but there was no makefile. (I navigated to GCC/gcc/go and could not find a makefile, instead finding a Make-lang.in)

EDIT:
I also went into GCC/libgo, but i could not find a makefile there either. I instead found Makefile.in, and Makefile.am. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531827/what-are-makefile-am-and-makefile-in) post about Makefile.in and Makefile.am. I ran `configure`, but it said

```
Program 'configure' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
+ configure
+ ~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ configure
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

EDIT 2:
I tried doing it in the MinGW terminal (going to C:/GCC/libgo running configure, then make), but I got the following error

```
./sysinfo.c:17:10: fatal error: ucontext.h: No such file or directory
   17 | #include <ucontext.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Also, when looking through the source code of sysinfo.c, I found a lot `#includes` starting with `<linux/somedir>`, but (as i said before) I am using windows

Comment: Maybe use Docker? Sounds like a lot more easier to me...

Comment: Do you know how I could use docker to install gccgo?

Comment: You would not *install* gccgo. You'd use the docker container and bind mounts to build your code...

Comment: Go compiler is still not supported in MinGW builds of GCC. See: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47726 but the compiler from https://golang.org/ works on Windows (and can be compiled from source using MinGW-w64).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A possible answer is WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux).

I tried gcc-go for you, my env is wsl(Arch):
[image]

Comment: WSL is not Windows, it is a full featured Linux that Windows just executes.  
Binaries compiled there will not work on Windows.  
Might as well say install a Linux VM, that's almost exactly the same thing, but the access to file system is easier on WSL.  
To me this question is unresolved.